# Send Date from Arduino Due to Nano 33 BLE

Tags: arduino, uart, serial-communication, arduino-due, arduino-nano

I'm trying to send data via UART from Due board to Nano board.

At first I try to send data from Nano to Due and it works.
But if I send the same data from Due to Nano it never receives it
and my `Serial1` is not available.

Here is the code sending data from Due to Nano which works.
Nano send data via `Serial1` to Due.

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.print('h');
  Serial.print('h');
}
```

Here Due receives the data.

```cpp
char r;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial1.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Serial1");
    r=Serial1.read();
    Serial.println(r);
  }
}
```

And now I want to send data from Due to Nano so I just switch the code.

Due should be sending with `Serial1` write or `Serial1` print and the code for Due now looks like.

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.print('h');
  Serial.print('h');
}
```

And nano should receive the data with serial read.

```cpp
char r;
void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial1.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Serial1");
    r=Serial1.read();
    Serial.println(r);
  }
}
```

But the `Serial1` is not available.

Do someone know where the problem could be?

Comment: is it really Nano 33 BLE as you have in the title? what do you mean by "but the Serial1 is not available"?

Comment: yes it's Nano 33 BLE and i can send data from it to DUE but not from DUE to Nano

Comment: what do you mean by "but the Serial1 is not available"?  it doesn't compile or Serial1.available() is always 0?